# What's the difference between these two bullets?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$.

1. Get the equation of the tangent place to the level set: $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|f(x,y,z)=k\}$ in the point $p$
2. Get the equation of the tangent hyperplane to the graphic of $f$ in the point $(p,f(p))$

I understand that the first bullet refers to a set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the second bullet to a set in $\mathbb{R}^4$ so I want to use the gradient like: $\langle\nabla f(p), x-p\rangle=0$

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct for problem #1. The normal vector to the tangent plane to a level set is $\nabla f$, so the equation of the plane is $\left< \nabla f(p), \, x-p\right> = 0$.

For problem #2, let $q = (x,y,z,w)$ be a generic point in $\Bbb{R}^4$, and $\pi(q) = (x,y,z)$ its projection to the 3-dimensional space. Then the tangent hyperplane to the graph of $f$ at $p$ is given by the equation $w - f(p) = \left< \nabla f(p), \, \pi(q)-p\right>$.

For example, if $f \colon \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, this reduces to the usual equation for the tangent line: $$y-f(a) = f'(a)(x-a)$$. In the case $f \colon \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$, this is the usual tangent plane equation: $$z - f(a,b) = f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b)$$